# How can I quickly go to sanctuary after a sidemission?

Tags: borderlands-2

We just completed the 'saving roland' mission, which was a long mission.
Now we wanted to play a quick side mission and went to deliver the pizza.
We defeated the turtles, but since we didn't found a way to go back or saw a travel post, we now have to go again through the 'saving roland' map/path, which is rather annoying if you played it only an hour before.

So the question is: how can you quickly go to sancutary if you completed your side mission?

Thanks

Comment: not sure what the exact trigger is - but whenever I've returned to the bloodshot hideout to do the turtles mission, there is another side-mission available there that requires you to continue to the dam, where there is a fast-travel..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make it to a fast travel station, as you are doing.

There's one near the end of the area where you rescued Roland, which sounds like the one you went to. There's also one near the entrance to the facility. You could have gone back to that one instead. I think it was probably closer.

Other than that, yeah, you're out of luck.

Comment: Yes, beginning of the map would definitely have been closer.  Sometimes not obvious where the "turtles" portion of the map exits out and I think it does prevent running back, but it should be obvious you're back in the main part of the map and can turn back around once you get to the whirlpool.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to get to a fast travel station is to just "Save and Quit", then "Continue" from the main menu. It's what I always do when I don't feel like walking back to a fast travel station.

Answer (score 0):

there is one where you save Roland at the dam but the one back at the beginning of the map is closer.